# The one where we hit the error of "The specified User is not a member of the specified Account."

Tags: docusignapi

When using ‘https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=92e53xxx9-4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2f893&redirect_uri=xxxxx’, after logging in to Docusign Account and obtaining AccessToken, calling CreateEnvelopes API returns the error'The specified User is not a member of the specified Account.'

[[add User][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEWFv.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f40cP.png)

I found that this User must be added in the User module before it can be used. For users who already have a Docusign account and they have paid for it, do they have to invite it? If an invitation is also required, how is the fee calculated?

What we need now is that users already have their own Docusign accounts and have paid for them. We help with the integration. The expenses are also directly deducted from their own Docusign accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many potential issues here.

First, When you call CreateEnvelopes API you need to provide an accountId (GUID) in the URL. That has to match the right account that you plan to use.

Second, you have account-d.docusign.com which is the developer env, but you are talking about

> users who already have a Docusign account and they have paid for it

That suggests a production account, which is account.docusign.com

You should also check the baseURI that you make API calls to, is that demo.docusign.net or something in production?

Generally speaking, a user must be a member of the account where you make API calls and the user is determined based on the authentication. However, users can be members of more than one account, so that's another potential wrinkle here.

> If an invitation is also required, how is the fee calculated?

Odd question for a developer forum, but yes, some accounts in production charge by seats, which means that if you have more users - you may get charged more, you will have to contact DocuSign Sales for details on your specific account plan and pricing.

Comment: So whether it is in developer or production,'a user must be a member of the account where you make API calls and the user is determined based on the authentication.' For production, the user has purchased the product in his own Docusign account. In this case, is the cost generated in the user's own Docusign account or in the integrated account ((AccountID (GUID) account)?

Comment: Whoever is the customer and uses DocuSign in production is the person that pays. If you are an ISV that develop applications that others will be using - you don't have to pay.

Comment: Ok noted, thanks for your reply.